# Calculating the maximum difference between two adjacent numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, difference

Recently I've been assigned a task which asks to me to "calculate the maximum difference between two adjacent numbers in the array that is passed to it". I'm fairly new to Java (I have only done VB in the past) and since this topic was not well explained to me, I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Here is some additional information about the task itself:

The function has to pass the following test. The function maxDiff should calculate the maximum difference between two adjacent numbers in the array that is passed to it.

```
@Test
public void assessmentTest() {
 int [] numbers = {12, 8, 34, 10, 59};
 assertEquals(49, maxDiff(numbers));
 int [] numbers2 = {-50, 100, 20, -40};
 assertEquals(150, maxDiff(numbers2));
}
```

Comment: Well, the logic is the same as in VB.  You iterate through array with a loop calculate differences and keep the maximum value. You can use [`Math.abs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) to get absolute values of results of your subtractions.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it's OK to ask here, but it is worth stating as much explicitly, so answers explain the concepts involved.

Answer (score 2):

You must assure to take the absolute difference, don't forget it. That's why I used the Math.abs() function.

```
public static int maxDiff(int[] numbers) {
      int diff = Math.abs(numbers[1] - numbers[0]);
      for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length-1; i++)
          if(Math.abs(numbers[i+1]-numbers[i]) > diff)
              diff = Math.abs(numbers[i+1] - numbers[i]);
      return diff;
}
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the list has less than two elements.

Comment: You're right except for a minor typo. If you do "i < number.length - 1" as the condition in the for loop you'll miss the last subtraction. I think you should either make it <= or  take out the minus one.

Comment: No, I won't miss the last one. I don't know if you realize that I substract [i+1] - [i]. I can't go until the last index, so I'll get an "index out of bounds" exception. That's why I went until the one before the last one. Got it?

Comment: Oops, I missed that part that you described. Yep, you are absolutely right.

Comment: `int diff = Math.abs(numbers[1] - numbers[0]);` will throw an exception if you don't have at least two elements in the list.

Comment: Don't worry about that. The question's author's already got his answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static int maxDiff(int[] numbers) {
      if (numbers.length < 2) {
          return 0;
      }
      if (numbers.length == 2) {
          return Math.abs(numbers[1] - numbers[0]);
      }
      int max = Math.abs(numbers[1] - numbers[0]);
      for (int i = 2; i < numbers.length; i++) {
          int diff = Math.abs(numbers[i-1] - numbers[i]);
          if (diff > max) {
              max = diff;
          }
      }
      return max;
}
```

Comment: This answer handles cases when the list is empty or has only 1 element. And runtime is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

For the specific question you asked:

```
public static int maxDiff(int[] arr) {
    if(arr.length < 2)
        return -1; // error condition: throw exception?

    int maxdiff = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        int diff = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i-1]);
        if(diff > maxdiff)
            maxdiff = diff;
    }

    return maxdiff;
}
```

If you want the max difference across all numbers in the array (not just adjacent ones) the most efficient way to do it would be to iterate the array just once to find the minimum and maximum, then return the absolute value of the two values subtracted from each other.

```
public static int maxDiff(int[] arr) {
    if(arr.length < 2) 
        return -1; // error condition: throw exception?

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if(arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
        if(arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i]; 
    }

    return Math.abs(max - min);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code can help you:

```
    int[] numbers = {12, 8, 34, 10, 59};

    int diff = 0;
    int previous = 0;

    for (int n : numbers) {
        diff = Math.max(diff, Math.abs(n - previous));
        previous = n;
    }
```

Variable "diff" will contain the value you look for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for Java;

```
int arrayMaximalAdjacentDifference(int[] inputArray) {
    int max=0;
    for( int i = 1 ; i < inputArray.length ; i++ ){
        max = Math.max(max,Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[i-1]));
    }
    return max;
}
```